# Как обработать ошибку в Blazor от Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor

Всем привет!
Есть два приложения:

1. Blazor server side
2. Web Api(написана давно)

В апишке у меня грубо говоря есть метод

```
public async Task<object> GetAllAsync(...)
{
   ...
   // Какая то проверка
   throw new Exception("Что то пошло не так");
   ...
}
```

В клиентском приложении у меня есть метод, который имеет примерный вид такой:

```
    public async Task GetAllAsync()
    {
            var httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient();
            var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{address}/api/foo");

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Если успешно
            }
            else
            {
                // Как получить сообщение об ошибке здесь?
            }
        }
    }
```

Вопрос заключается в следущем: как правильно обработать ошибку такого вида от апи?

**ps**

нашел такой вариант

```
var exception = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpError>();
```

но HttpError тянет зависимость с .NetFramework 4.6(а изначально использую .net core 3 preview)

Answer (score -1):

Документация говорит, что GetAsync выдает System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException, так что просто можно использовать try/catch.

Comment: и далее написано, в каких случаях выводится эта ошибка: "The request failed due to an underlying issue such as network connectivity, DNS failure, server certificate validation or timeout."

Comment: в моем случае возвращается Task<HttpResponseMessage>, в котором уже можно просмотреть, является ли ответ ошибочным или нет.